# Getting the current value of a select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, select

When I try to get the selected `option` in a `select` tag in the current DOM

`var type = $("input[name='type']").val();`

I get as returned value `undefined`.

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
                                <option value="combine">Combiné</option>
                                <option value="histogramme">Histogramme</option>
                                <option value="courbe">Courbe</option>
                                <option value="cercle">Cercle</option>
                            </select>
```

Why do I get this, please?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
var type = $("select[name='type']").find(":selected").text();
```

If you want `val()` to work, you need to make sure your **option** tags have their `value` properties set, otherwise you'll want to do the above.

---

Since you updated your post, you can simply do:

```
var type = $("#type").val();
```

If you want to check for undefined, you need to do:

```
if (type === undefined)
    // do something
```

Comment: At final, I've combined all your three solutions to deal this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you selector is wrong, the element selector must be `select` not `input`

```
var type = $("select[name='type']").val();
```

your code looks for an input element with name type instead of a select element like

```
<input name="type" type="..." />
```

instead of

```
<select name="type">
    .....
</select>
```

Comment: @user3319426 since you have an id `var type = $("#type").val();` also will do - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d4P5L/3/

Comment: How to check if the current value is `undefined`, please?

Comment: the problem was, that jQuery couldn't detect the dynamically selected `option` tag that I was done using `Razor`, so it always takes the default value = `undefined`. So, I had to use the three solutions of CodeMaverick to get current selected `option` tag. Thank you so much Arun P Johny !

Answer (score 0):

```
var type = $("select[name='type']").val();
```

Comment: Whoops, had a `}` instead of the `"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
<select onChange={(e) => setigst((Number(subT) / 100) * Number(e.target.value))}>
            <option>0</option>
            <option>5%</option>
            <option>12%</option>
            <option>18%</option>
            <option>28%</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).